# MySQL Replace Escaping Error

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to do a replace and am getting a 1064 error.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = replace(post_content, ‘<p style="text-align: center">Click here to see more’, ‘<p style="text-align: center">See more’)
```

I am guessing I need to escape something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just using the wrong apostrophe.  Use `'` instead of `‘`:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET post_content = replace(post_content, 
    '<p style="text-align: center">Click here to see more', 
    '<p style="text-align: center">See more')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dde75/1)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed some "escapes" were necessary:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = replace(post_content, '<p style=\"text-align: center\">Click here to see more', '<p style=\"text-align: center\">See more')
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!